# The aggregate effects of human-human interaction

Tags: human-nature, relations

It can be seen that individual human-human interactions vary widely, from positive to neutral to negative.

However, I have no empirical evidence on the effects of human-human interactions as an aggregate.

My hypothesis is that human-human interactions individually vary in degree of good, but in the aggregate over a long period of time, it would be a net negative.

Is there a theory that would prove/disprove my hypothesis?

Thank you.

Comment: A theory would not, but you are free to conduct some experiments. If you surveyed people, the most common response would probably be: "*It beats the alternative.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hypothesis cannot be proven or unproven not least because there is no accepted way to quantify the degree of 'goodness' in an individual interaction, nor any accepted calculus for determining an aggregate degree of goodness from individual instances.

Comment: And no one wants to volunteer for the experiment of solitary confinement.

Comment: @ScottRowe Indeed! Although sometimes I fancy the idea of a short spell of solitary confinement- ideally in a luxury spa with an extensive library.

Comment: Yeah, as a child my family spent the entire summer in a cabin on a remote island with no TV, radio, telephone, running water etc. Got lots of reading done.